# Add STOMP header without recreating Message on ChannelInterceptorAdapter

Tags: spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I need to add header to a STOMP message currently it is working as below but i am recreating the message , is it possible to just add native header without having to recreate the message for performance .

```
public class MyChannelInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {


    @Override
      public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);

        StompCommand command = accessor.getCommand();
        if(command != null) {
            log.debug("Receiving msg {} from {}",command,accessor.getUser().getName());
            if(command == StompCommand.SEND) {
                log.debug("Adding expires header to  msg {} from {}",command,accessor.getUser().getName());
                String ttlString = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("ttl");
                long ttl = 30000;
                try {
                    ttl = Long.parseLong(ttlString);
                } 
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    log.error("TTL header received but not in correct format {}",ttlString);
                }
                accessor.addNativeHeader("expires", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() + ttl));

                return MessageBuilder.createMessage(message.getPayload(), accessor.getMessageHeaders());
            }
        }
        return message;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what i was looking for

```
StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
```

The above code will get the actual StompHeaderAccessor of the message so if you manipulate the native headers they are directly reflected on the message while

```
StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
```

will get a clone of the headers and you have to create a new message with the new cloned headers

full fixed code below

```
@Override
      public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
       // StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        if(accessor != null) {
            StompCommand command = accessor.getCommand();
            if(command != null) {
                log.debug("Receiving msg {} from {}",command,accessor.getUser().getName());
                if(command == StompCommand.SEND) {

                    log.debug("Adding expires header to  msg {} from {}",command,accessor.getUser().getName());
                    String ttlString = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("ttl");
                    long ttl = 30000;
                    if(ttlString != null) {
                        try {
                            ttl = Long.parseLong(ttlString);
                        } 
                        catch(Exception ex) {
                            log.error("TTL header received but not in correct format {}",ttlString);
                        }
                    }

                    accessor.addNativeHeader("expires", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() + ttl));
                     // I don't need any more to create a new message
                    //return MessageBuilder.createMessage(message.getPayload(), accessor.getMessageHeaders());
                }
            }
        }
        return message;
      }
```

Comment: You saved my day. In my case I did have to create a new message. I modify the SUBSCRIBE frame in the beforeHandle() method.

Answer (score 0):

Since `addNativeHeader` succeeds, that indicates the message is still mutable - see `addNativeHeader()`.

In any case, since the `NATIVE_HEADERS` message header is a `MultiValueMap`-valued header, you can update the header contents in-place.

Hence, there is no need to create a new message.

You **would** have to create a new message if you add a new header to the message itself (rather than updating the mutable contents of an existing header).

**EDIT**

I just ran a test; as long as the message is still mutable, you can change it...

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    MutableMessageHeaders headers = new MutableMessageHeaders(map);
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.createMessage("foo", headers);
    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    accessor.addNativeHeader("foo", "bar");
    System.out.println(message.getHeaders().get(NativeMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS));
    accessor.setImmutable();
    try {
        accessor.addNativeHeader("baz", "qux");
        fail("expected IllegalStateException");
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    }
}
```

That said, are you experiencing a performance problem or is this just a perceived issue. Message creation is not expensive.

Comment: How will I then tell the message to get updated with the new accessor and it is not getting the new headed added

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; the accessor simply wraps the message; as long as the message is still mutable, you can add new headers. If it was already immutable, the `addNativeHeader` would fail.

Comment: i made assumption that creating message is heavy , what i tried is commenting out return MessageBuilder.createMessage ... , but the result is message is returned exactly as it came without the expires header added